# setState when changing value on a <select>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drop-down-menu, setstate

I have two `<select>` inputs. I want to set the attribute as "disable" one of them at a specific value option from the other `<select>`.

The first one is:

```
<select ref="selectOption">
   <option selected value="1" >Option 1</option>
   <option value="2" >Option 2</option>
</select>

<select ref="selectTime" disabled={this.state.disabled}>
   <option value="a" >January</option>
   <option value="b" >Febreaury</option>
</select>
```

So, my idea is to set the state of the 2nd `<select>` as false when the option value = 2 from the first `<select>`

How can I do it? Or is there another way without react that I can do it? or with props? I'm pretty confused. I tried to do something like:

```
var option= ReactDom.findDOMNode(this.refs.selectOption).value;
if( option == '2' ) this.setState({disabled:true});
```

But it's not working. Tried to put it in componentDidUpdate but the component is not updating when I select a new value from the select, so that won't work. Ideas please.

EDIT:

I also have this solution with jquery but I want to use Reactjs.

```
$('#selectOption').change(function() {
    $('#selectTime').prop('disabled', false);
    if ($(this).val() == '2') {
        $('#selectTime').prop('disabled', true);
    }
})
```

I'm pretty confused on how to use ReactDom.findDOMNode(this.refs.selectOption) instead the jquery selectors

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a minimal example of how you could accomplish this, add an `onChange` event handler to your first select, `setState` in the event handler based on the value:

```
handleChange(event) {
    let value = event.target.value;
    this.setState({
        disabled: value == '2'
    });
}
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <select ref="selectOption" onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e)}>
               <option selected value="1" >Option 1</option>
               <option value="2" >Option 2</option>
            </select>

            <select ref="selectTime" disabled={this.state.disabled}>
               <option value="a" >January</option>
               <option value="b" >Febreaury</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 4):

That would be the react way to achieve this:

```
export default class Test extends Component{

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      selectOptionValue: '1'
    }
  }

  handleOnChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      selectOptionValue: e.target.value
    })
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <select defaultValue = "1" onChange={this.handleOnChange}>
          <option value="1" >Option 1</option>
          <option value="2" >Option 2</option>
        </select>

        <select  disabled={ this.state.selectOptionValue === '2' }>
          <option value="a" >January</option>
          <option value="b" >Febreaury</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This answer and the @rob-m was I was trying to find. I'll pick this answer as correct only because was the first one.

Answer (score 0):

How about `onChange` event from [this](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#the-select-tag) ? For your convenience:

```js
class FlavorForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: 'coconut'};

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    alert('Your favorite flavor is: ' + this.state.value);
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Pick your favorite La Croix flavor:
          <select value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}>
            <option value="grapefruit">Grapefruit</option>
            <option value="lime">Lime</option>
            <option value="coconut">Coconut</option>
            <option value="mango">Mango</option>
          </select>
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep it simple and use pure javascript, you could just use the following snippet.

```js
document.querySelector('select[ref="selectOption"]').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  document.querySelector('select[ref="selectTime"]').disabled = (e.target.value === '2') ? true : false;
})
```

```html
<select ref="selectOption">
  <option selected value="1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="2">Option 2</option>
</select>

<select ref="selectTime">
  <option value="a">January</option>
  <option value="b">Febreaury</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach to define which state variable needs to be set.

```
state = { someStateVariable : "" }

render() {
    return (
        <select onChange={event => this._setSelected({ someStateVariable: event.target.value })}>
            <option value="1">One</option>
            ...
        </select>
    );
}

_setSelected = newState => {
    this.setState(newState)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 - Create state and set initial value an empty string

```
      const [category,setCategory] = useState('');
```

Step 2 Map youre options and check id in the option value === select value then set selected to true

```
  const renderedResults = results.map((result) => {
    const selected = category === result.id ? "true" : '';
    return (
      <option selected={selected} key={result._id} value={result._id}>{result?.name}</option>
      );
  });
```

Step 3

```
 <select
   onChange={(e) => {
    setCategory(e.target.value);
   }}
   className="form-select"
   aria-label={"Default select example"}
   >
   <option value="">Select a category</option>
     {renderedResults}
 </select>
```

Comment: Thanks buddy, but React Hooks (2019) wasn't invented yet in 2016, but for people finding a way now and is reading this old question could be helpful